# convert seconds to {H hr MM min} time format with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert seconds to (H hr mm min) format by Javascript?
Example : 4 hr 30 min
I found other solutions here, but they didn't help me.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: i don't want the current time; i want to use my custom second to convert it to H hr MM min format e.g. : 3 hr 22 min

Comment: Date constructor accepts custom date parameter(s), you can construct dates like this: `new Date ( year, month, date, hour, minute, second )`. Look at accepted answer on link I give you (look at links in answer too), there you have detail answer regarding date manipulation in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hours is

```
(total_seconds / 60) / 60
```

minutes is

```
(total_seconds / 60) % 60
```

seconds is

```
(total_seconds % 60) % 60
```

where `/` is integer division (division that discards the remainder) and `%` is the modulo function.

Comment: There's no such thing called "integer division" in JavaScript. `1/3 = 0.3333.....`, not `0`. You have to use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to discard the fraction.

Comment: i'm referring to the mathematical operation; integer division in javascript can be implemented as `Math.foor(a/b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript's built-in `Date` function:

```
// Randomly selected number of seconds
var seconds = 23568;

// Pass it to the Date-constructor (year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds)
var d = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, seconds);

// Get result as a "formatted" string, and show it.
var myString = d.getHours().toString() + ':' + d.getMinutes().toString() + ':' + d.getSeconds().toString();
alert(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the given code which will convert seconds into hh-mm-ss format:

```
var measuredTime = new Date(null);
measuredTime.setSeconds(4995); // specify value of SECONDS
var MHSTime = measuredTime.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
```

Source: [Convert seconds to HH-MM-SS format in JavaScript](https://www.codespeedy.com/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-format-in-javascript/)